# how to create a Pagination with if and for loop django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I tried to do Pagination using **for and if** and it didn't work
So how do I do that

this an image that can show u
[front page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9akaP.png)

[page 2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYzOC.png)

front page code

```
  {% for post in posts %}
  {% if forloop.counter <= 2 %}
    <div style="background-color: #9999;" class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 100%;">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}"><img style="height: 200px; width: 330px;" src="{{ post.mainimage.url }}" class="card-img" alt="..."></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="ph">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title }} , {{ post.xnumber }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ post.version }}</p>
            <p>{{ post.category }}</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_added }}</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <hr >
  {% endif %}
  {% empty %}
  <div class="notification">
      <p>No posts yet!</p>
  </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

page 2 code

```
  {% for post in posts %}
  {% if forloop.counter2 <= 30 %}
    <div style="background-color: #9999;" class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 100%;">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}"><img style="height: 200px; width: 330px;" src="{{ post.mainimage.url }}" class="card-img" alt="..."></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="ph">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title }} , {{ post.xnumber }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ post.version }}</p>
            <p>{{ post.category }}</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_added }}</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <hr >
  
  {% endif %}
  {% empty %}
      <div class="notification">
          <p>No posts yet!</p>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

so pls help
i did this but its not work no posts show in the page 2

Comment: You are not even supposed to be checking the number of posts from the frontend and you are not supposed to have two pages to paginate . Can you share your list view?

Comment: ```
def frontpage(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    
    return render(request, 'posts/frontpage.html', {'posts': posts})

def p2(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    
    return render(request, 'posts/2.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Comment: what i need to do that if the front page has 3 posts the other posts go to the page 2

Comment: Okay, yes you need to paginate the page but NO need of creating another html page you can achieve this on a single page, can you share your ``` def frontpage(request):``` please?

Comment: sure `
def frontpage(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    
    return render(request, 'posts/frontpage.html', {'posts': posts})`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can approach this using the [Paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/#the-paginator-class) class provided by Django.

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render

from yourApp.models import Post

def frontpage(request): 
    posts = Post.objects.all() 
        
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 3) # Show 3 posts per page or 10 to show 10 posts.
    
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    return render(request, 'posts/frontpage.html', {'page_obj': page_obj})
```

Now in your frontedend html page all you have to do is make this minor change and your html code will look like this

```
 {% for post in page_obj %}
    <div style="background-color: #9999;" class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 100%;">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}"><img style="height: 200px; width: 330px;" src="{{ post.mainimage.url }}" class="card-img" alt="..."></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="ph">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title }} , {{ post.xnumber }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ post.version }}</p>
            <p>{{ post.category }}</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_added }}</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <hr >

  {% empty %}
  <div class="notification">
      <p>No posts yet!</p>
  </div>
{% endfor %} 

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Now the next thing is just style the pagination div. I hope this will solve your pagination issue. Thank you